# Parallelize nested loop with running sum in Fortran

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, fortran, sparse-matrix

I would like to understand if it is possible to parallelize the following nested loop (using OpenMP in Fortran).

To give some background information, I am doing this to initialize a sparse matrix. It turns out that the matrix-vector multiplication is very fast, thanks to the sparse BLAS library. The bottleneck in the code is however the loops that I do to create the COO representation of the matrix (row index, col index and nonzero values). So the question is whether it is possible to parallelize this (perhaps using a reduction  clause):

```
nnz = N*N
        allocate(row_ind(nnz),col_ind(nnz),values(nnz),stat=istat)
        if (istat/=0) then
            error stop "Allocation of row_ind,col_ind,values failed"
        endif

        counter = 1
        do iz = 1,n_z
            do ia = 1,n_a
                ix = (iz-1)*n_a+ia
                opt_ind = pol_ap_ind(ia,iz)
                do izp = 1,n_z
                    if (Pi(iz,izp)/=0.0d0) then
                        ixp = (izp-1)*n_a+opt_ind
                        values(counter) = Pi(iz,izp) 
                        row_ind(counter) = ix
                        col_ind(counter) = ixp
                        counter = counter+1
                    endif 
                enddo
            enddo
        enddo
        nnz = counter -1
        row_ind = row_ind(1:nnz)
        col_ind = col_ind(1:nnz)
        values = values(1:nnz)
```

Comment: The loop carried dependency on `counter` prevent any trivial parallelization, but I think you can split the loop in two parts. A first sequential step prepare the work for the second step and the second step is parallel. It will not be much faster if the loop is not vectorized. The thing is `Pi(iz,izp)` access seems not contiguous. If you transpose the array, it should be OK AFAIK. You should store indices of chunks in an array for the first step so the second step can work in parallel on it. I think I am not fluent enough in Fortran to provide a working answer, but the idea seems to work.